# Crystal Reports: displaying array as fields dynamically

Tags: arrays, crystal-reports

I've developed a report to capture the last day of each month in a range of dates selected by the end user via parameter. The report works and stores the dates in a DateVar array, however I would like it to display each date as a separate row or column of data. I am using these dates to determine how many employees were active or on a leave during any given month, by finding the most recent status begin date. The only reason I mention is is because there are calculations that must occur in the details section. Whatever solution needs to occur in the report footer. A cross-tab would be perfect, but from what I can tell you can't make arrays formula fields. Currently I am using the below formula to display the values in the array as a pipe delimited string, but this is less than ideal.

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
datevar array MonthEndDates;
stringvar MEDD:="Month End Dates|";
local numbervar i;

for i:=1 to ubound(MonthEndDates) do 
MEDD:= (MEDD & totext(MonthEndDates[i],"MM/dd/yyyy") &" | ");
MEDD
```

Currently this returns the following:

```
Month End Dates|08/31/2013 | 09/30/2013 | 10/31/2013 | 11/30/2013 | 12/31/2013 |01/31/2014 | 02/28/2014 | 03/31/2014 | 04/30/2014 | 05/31/2014 | 06/30/2014 | 07/31/2014 |
```

What I was hoping for is individual cells for each date. Right now I am creating the below formula for each subscript

```
//created for each subscript
WhilePrintingRecords;
datevar array MonthEndDates;
MonthEndDates[1];
```

But I am hoping for a solution that creates a single cell for each date, regardless of how large the date range that is selected. Currently the results are limited by how many of these formulas I create. Any suggestions on how to better display array's values? thanks for reading!

Comment: Why is your solution "less than ideal"? How would you instead want the array to display?

Comment: I couldn't understand your exact requirement?.... any sample data on how you want the report to display will be helpful

Comment: thanks for the comments, I appreciate the feedback. I've updated my question.

Comment: There is no way to do this with your current approach, but there are likely better workarounds anyway that don't involve arrays. You can easily get the last day of the month in a single formula. How, specifically, do these EOM dates come into play in your report? How are they displayed in the report or used for calculations?